# App Engine image resizing feature for plain Google Cloud Storage usage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage as my CDN backend to save images for user content. However when loading those images I did not yet implemented a way to scaled them by a specific width. That makes my thumbnail renderings very heavy regarding to the image size and that's not nice.

So while I was trying to implement "Scrimage" as a library to manipulate my images before I pass them to the requesting frontend I stumpled over this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/#transforming-images

It shows how you can create a "functional URL" that takes parameters and manipulates images when requested.

I wonder if this feature is usable for my Java backend as well without the need of AppEngine? Or does Google Cloud Storage already has that implemented so I can call my storage image URLs with the mentioned parameters to resize the images?

I couldn't find anything therefore I am asking here.

Comment: I will point out that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it's seeking references for products and services.  You'll probably get a better result if you post to Reddit instead to open this up to general discussion. https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/

Answer (score 1):

GCS doesn't have that implemented.

You're referring to the images API which is one of Google App Engine's [bundled  Services API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/support-for-app-engine-services-in-second-generation-runtimes). My understanding is that they can't be used outside of a GAE App